# Python Implementing the KNN method

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-complexity, knn

i'm trying to manually code KNN classification method. I defined two function, one is to calculate the Euclidean distance and the other is for classifying the given sample. Here are the code:

```
def Distance(train,test,i):
    dis=np.array([])
    for k in range(train.shape[0]):
        e_dis = np.linalg.norm(train[k]-test[i])
        dis = np.append(dis,e_dis)
    dis=np.argsort(dis)
    return dis
```

```
def predict(label_set,dis,k):
    unique,counts=np.unique(label_set[dis[:k]], return_counts=True)
    index=np.argsort(counts)
    predict=unique[index[-1]]
    return predict
```

Now i try to define the real KNN function which combine these two together using for loop to get the prediction on every given sample from the test dataset.

```
def knn(train,test,label_set,k):
    prediction=np.array([])
    for i in range (test.shape[0]):
        dis=Distance(train,test,i)
        pred=predict(label_set,dis,k)
        prediction=np.append(prediction,pred)
    return prediction
```

Here below is what i tried to run the code. Setting k=10 to find 10 nearest neighbors to do the classification.

```
b=knn(ftrain_set,ftest_set,ltrain_set,10)
```

The Distance and predict function works fine when i tested them. When i tested my knn function, it takes a very long time to run it. I acknowledge my knn function takes O(n*k*logn) where n,k are the sample size for train and test set.

Now i'm seeking some methods to reduce the time complexity so i could calculate the accuracy for each k then draw a study curve to find the best k parameter. Could anyone help me on reduce the time complexity for my knn function? Thank you in advance!

Comment: seems like their is dimension mismatch between your input data and labels.

Comment: @sai Hi, so beside the dimension mismatching problem, my knn function should logically work correctly? Thank You

Comment: Hi, I think so.

Comment: @sai Thank you for your advice. I now fixed it and the function is running now!Thank you

Comment: Cool! good to know.